# How do I echo a clickable URL in PHP?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, echo, href

How do I echo a clickable URL in PHP?
i want to makes this code as a clickable link, so i can click it, but i got no idea how to make it. Please help me if you know this case.

[picture of the problem code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T99DX.png)

and these are my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Detail Shelter</div>
        <div class="card-body">

        <?php foreach($shelter as $slt): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url().'/upload/'.$slt->gambar ?>" class="card-img-top">
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nama Shelter</td>
                        <td><strong></strong><?php echo $slt->nama_shelter ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lokasi Shelter</td>
                        <td><strong></strong><?php echo $slt->lokasi_shelter?></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Deskripsi</td>
                        <td><strong></strong><?php echo $slt->deskripsi ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Telpon</td>
                        <td><strong></strong><?php echo $slt->no_telp ?></td>
                    </tr>


                 </table>

                <?php echo anchor('dashboard/index',
                '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Kembali </div>') ?>    
            
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You tagged this with `hyperlink` and `href` already, and yet you _still_ don’t know what HTML you need to create …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this : `<a href="<?php echo $slt->lokasi_shelter; ?>" class="">click here</a>`

Answer (score 1):

To make a link clickable you need to use the  tag see [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Lokasi Shelter</td>
    <td><strong></strong><a href="<?php echo $slt->lokasi_shelter?>">LINK TEXT</a></td>
</tr>
```

assuming the link you want is `<?php echo $slt->lokasi_shelter?>`